# Wtforms and Twitter Bootstrap How to lay forms side-by-side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask-wtforms

I'm currently working on an application using Flask with Wtforms and Twitter Bootstrap. I have a Registration form that incorporates the Personal and Address. I feel it is rather long so I'll like to lay the forms out side-by-side. That is have the Personal details section on the left and the address on the right.

From what I have gathered so for, I have to create the Personal detail form and subclass it in the Address form.

If the above is correct, how then can I get Bootstrap to lay them out side-by-side? I have to admit this is my first time using both libraries so I haven't spent much time in the documentation. I however need to use them for the application I'm working on. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Where are your attempts at solving this problem?

Comment: At the moment I've only created the Address form which subclasses the Personal form. Then I created the Registration form which subclasses the Address form. The there is only one submit button to submit all the data one time. I haven't done anything on the Bootstrap side of things yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [the Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for this. Something along these lines (refer to the documentation for details):

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">personal form fields go here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">address form fields go here</div>
  </div>
</form>
```